# C# winform: serialize/deserialize JSON data coming from REST service to use in application

Tags: json.net

I have Grid view and binding it to the data calling from REST based web service.
REST service is giving it in JSON format, so how i can deserialize and use for my grid?

Here is the most of code I have,

```
public ICollection<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(GetEndPointAddress("GetEmployeeService"));
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ICollection<Employee>));
        var employees = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as ICollection<Employee>;
        response.Close();
        return employees;
    }

public Uri GetServiceBaseAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri("http://localhost/Employeeservices/api");

        }
    }

private Uri GetEndPointAddress(string relativeAddress)
    {
        return new Uri(GetServiceBaseAddress.ToString() + "/" + relativeAddress);
    }
```

I am getting below error:

There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[EmployeeApp.Models.Employee, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. The data at the root level is invalid. Line

Also, how can I post the data back to the service if I make changes to any of these data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using DataContractSerializer, which is an XML serializer. You can't use an XML serializer and expect it to deserialize JSON data, because they're two completely different data formats.

First, consider whether using DataContractJsonSerializer is an option for you at all. My guess is that it is not, because using DCJS comes with its own set of requirements, constraints, and terminology that you most likely are either not familiar with, have little flexibility to use or get familiar with, or is just overkill. To explore whether this is an option, check out [the JSON API reference](http://ttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412187.aspx) and the [stand-alone JSON serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412187.aspx) samples.

My best recommendation is that you use the Json .NET framework. See http://json.codeplex.com/ to see what you can do with it -- it's probably the easiest way you can get started with .NET and JSON.